# Convert from NSMutableArray to JSON in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` with objects and i want convert it to JSON to send Web Service a `NSString` with it information.

I have SBJSON and JSONKit frameworks, but i can't do it. Im doing it with:

```
 NSString *JSONData=[mutablearray JSONRepresentation];

 NSString *JSONData=[mutablearray JSONString];
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What is meant "i can't do it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object,nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSString* jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can now send jsonData to the server.. Hope it helps !

Comment: This is giving error for me -JSONRepresentation failed. Error is: JSON serialisation not supported for NSConcreteValue
. i am trying to convert my NSMutableArray to JSON .....PLease help

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to try another JSON-Library you should try Touch-Json: https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON

and then serialize your array with the following code:

```
 NSData *data = [[[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeArray:array error:nil];
```